# How to UNIT test Spring @PreAuthorize(hasAuthority)?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I want to be able to unit test this service but not sure what the best way to go about it is. I have unit tests complete for the service but they currently work without a mock user or permission attached it.

The service looks as follows:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('can-modify-users')")
@Transactional
public void delete(Integer id) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    repository.delete(id);
}
```

This is called by the controller:

```
@DeleteMapping("/users/{id}") 
    public void delete(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        service.delete(id);
    }
```

I know that the PreAuthorize annotation works as I've user tested it but having difficultly testing that in a unit test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the best way to unit test was to use the @Autowired annotation on the service so the correct security context was being used. I used @MockBean for any repositories used in the service. For example:

```
@Autowired
UserService userService;

@MockBean
UserRepository userRepository;  

@Test
@WithMockUser(authorities = "can-modify-users")
public void testDeleteUserByIdService_WithAuth() {
    //Given
    Integer idDeleting = 123;

    //When
    userService.delete(idDeleting);

    //Then
    verify(userRepository).delete(idDeleting);
}

@Test(expected = AccessDeniedException.class)
@WithMockUser
public void testDeleteUserByIdService_WithoutAuth() {
    //Given
    Integer idDeleting = 123;

    //When/Then
    userService.delete(idDeleting);
}
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem!